# Serial PCIE not detected?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, pci-express, serial-port

I have a "Moschip PCIe 9922 Multi-I/O Controller" 2x serial PCI-E card that I'm trying to get working on Ubuntu 13.04.

lspci shows the controllers fine, but "dmesg | grep tty" isn't showing them.

```
$ lspci
01:00.0 Serial controller: MosChip Semiconductor Technology Ltd. PCIe 9922 Multi-I/O Controller
01:00.1 Serial controller: MosChip Semiconductor Technology Ltd. PCIe 9922 Multi-I/O Controller
```

..

```
$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
```

..

```
$ sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS*
/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS10, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS11, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS12, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS13, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS14, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS15, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS16, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS17, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS18, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS19, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS20, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS21, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS22, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS23, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS24, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS25, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS26, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS27, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS28, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS29, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS30, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS31, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS4, UART: unknown, Port: 0x3008, IRQ: 28
/dev/ttyS5, UART: unknown, Port: 0x3000, IRQ: 29
/dev/ttyS6, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS7, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS8, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS9, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
```

Is there something that I'm missing here? Do I just need to set it with setserial? How would I do that?

I have pretty much the same port on a 12.10 machine that seems to detect fine, and it's going to ttyS4/ttyS5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem on the same brand of card. I came up with a solution.

First, I have a UEFI BIOS that completely ignored the card, so I had to change some settings related to legacy PCI option ROMs or something for it to show up on lspci at all. Then, issue an "lspci -v" and look for the IRQ's on the card as well as the I/O ports.

```
# lspci -v
```

My card is a 6-port serial card and shows up as 3 PCI devices, one with 4 ports and 2 with one port each. The PCI device with 4 port lists IRQ 19 and I/O ports at d000, d010, d020 and d030. The remaining two ports are on d040 and d050 with IRQ 18 and 17 respectively. I'll use this in my example below:

```
setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart none
setserial /dev/ttyS1 uart none
setserial /dev/ttyS2 uart none
setserial /dev/ttyS3 uart none
setserial /dev/ttyS4 uart none
setserial /dev/ttyS5 uart none
```

(This prevents errors when using settings which may be wrongly autodetected and frees you up to allocate the devices as you like:)

```
setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A port 0xd000 irq 19
setserial /dev/ttyS1 uart 16550A port 0xd010 irq 19
setserial /dev/ttyS2 uart 16550A port 0xd020 irq 19
setserial /dev/ttyS3 uart 16550A port 0xd030 irq 19
setserial /dev/ttyS4 uart 16550A port 0xd040 irq 18
setserial /dev/ttyS5 uart 16550A port 0xd050 irq 17
```

I still need to figure out how to avoid needing this in rc.local and rather do it in modprobe.d (If anyone would be so kind so as to enlighten us! Thanks!)

Also being able to change the IRQ's would be nice, but I think this is handled by the BIOS - or possibly UEFI (if I can find documentation anywhere!?) (assuming it's not hard-wired on the card, which is also possible).

Comment: Yeah, the issue was that it already showed fine in lspci though. Changing serial cards fixed the issue, so I don't know if it was a bios issue.

Comment: It's fairly common for some cards not to work in some slots... but if you only have one slot unless you want to dig really deep!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to have been the card not working on that specific board. I guess the drivers weren't working.

Comment: @Tog This is the asker giving a self-answer.